# Multiple instances of filepicker.io on the same page?

Tags: filepicker.io

Is it possible to have multiple instances of filepicker.io on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple instances are allowed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little?  When I have multiple instances and I instantiate one I get events fired for every instance on the page.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or similar code snippet to demonstrate what's going on?